# JavaScript - When I declare a var named 'location', it gets sent to the URL?

Tags: javascript

I just encountered the weirdest thing ever.

When I declare a variable called 'location', whatever the value of the variable gets sent to the URL.

```
var location = 1;
// Results in http://localhost:8000/1

var location = document.getElementById('element');
// Results in http://localhost:8000/[object%20HTMLSelectElement]
```

This only happens for `location`.  If I use let's say `locations`:

```
var location2 = 1;
// Nothing weird happens
```

I'm using Django.  I checked both my frontend and backend code and there doesn't seem to be any conflicting names.

What could be causing this?

Comment: this is a duplicate, and now you're learning why global variables are a bad idea

Comment: Location is already a reserve keyword there.

Comment: Ahh okay.  I spent too long on this.  Thanks.

Comment: `location` is a host object containing information about the page that is currently loaded. Please do not use the reserved keyword as variables. http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`location` is a builtin property of the `window` and `document` objects. It's accessible without putting `window.location`, though, so that's why you are noticing that it already has a special meaning. It stores the URL. If you change it, it changes the URL; or, if you change or read one of it's properties (e.g. doing `location.hash="part-7"`) you can change or read parts of the URL, or things related to it.

For example:

```js
console.log(location)
```

There are certain variables in JavaScript that just already exist. Another example is `document`; or `window`; etc.

You can read more about `location` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location

Answer (score 1):

`location` is a window property. When assigning anything to `location` it will try to redirect to that location.

You can rename your variable so that it doesn't conflict with any of the window properties that have special meaning.

Or make it a local variable inside a function with `IIFE` (Immediately Invocable Function Expression):

```
(function() {
  var location = '';
})();
```